# Conditional TTY Allocation in Docker Compose, Interactive Mode Issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, arguments

I'm currently working on a Docker Compose setup where I want to conditionally allocate a TTY (terminal) to a container based on the value of an `ARG` variable called `CONTINUOUS_RUN`. Specifically, if `CONTINUOUS_RUN` is set to `true`, I want to allocate a TTY (`tty: true`), and if it's set to any other value or not set at all, I want to disable TTY (`tty: false`).

Here's the relevant part of my Docker Compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tty: ${CONTINUOUS_RUN:-false}
```

To ensure that `CONTINUOUS_RUN` is indeed set to `true` when needed, I've added a verification step in my Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.5-alpine3.18

# Check if CONTINUOUS_RUN is true
ARG CONTINUOUS_RUN=true
```

My expectation was that this setup would conditionally allocate a TTY based on the value of `CONTINUOUS_RUN` and that the verification step in the Dockerfile would confirm that `CONTINUOUS_RUN` is set to `true` when needed.

However, I've encountered an additional issue: even when `CONTINUOUS_RUN` is set to `true`, interactive mode with the detached container (`-d`) is not working as expected. I'm unable to interact with the running container.

Is there something I'm missing in my Docker Compose configuration or Dockerfile that's causing this issue with interactive mode, even when `CONTINUOUS_RUN` is set to `true`?

Comment: I wonder from your higher-level description if you want to [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/) a temporary container for the case where you need to allocate a tty and interact with the container's stdin, and omit the `tty:` option from the Compose file entirely.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different "sets" of environment variables when you run a container.  Compose settings like `tty:` only consider the host's environment and the contents of the host's `.env` file at the point where you run a `docker-compose` command; they don't see the contents of the image at all.  Inside the container, conversely, commands see only the image's `ENV` values and the Compose `environment:` and `env_file:` settings, but not the host environment.

Dockerfile `ARG` doesn't do any kind of "verification" and it doesn't see what the eventual values of the host environment will be.  During the image build process, `RUN` commands will see an environment variable `CONTINUOUS_RUN`, which will have a string value `true` unless the Compose `build: { args: }` sets this to a different value.  This all happens before anything outside in the `build:` block is considered, and it's very possible to run the same container with and without an attached tty.

In the first paragraph of the question you specify that the `CONTINUOUS_RUN` setting is built into the image via a Dockerfile `ARG`.  You can't really set Compose settings based on the contents of the image like this, and in general it's hard to read out `ARG` values after an image is built.  Since you're describing two separate images, you may want two separate Compose containers

```yaml
services:
  with-continuous-run:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        CONTINUOUS_RUN: 'true'
    tty: true
  without-continuous-run:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        CONTINUOUS_RUN: 'false'
```

It's also possible that your container could detect whether or not there is a tty directly, without building it in to the image.  A shell command `test -t /dev/stdin` will return true (exit code 0) if the container was started with a tty and false (exit code 1) if not; you may be able to do a similar test in code.  You could do this in an entrypoint wrapper script or somewhere in your program's setup.  This would let you use the same image in both contexts, without a specific `ARG`.